# How to avoid escaping references in Dart?

Tags: dart

Dart is pass-by and return-by reference, meaning that if I have a class which contains a member instance of another class, and I want to return this using a **get** function, the caller of this function has direct access to mutate the data inside that member instance.

For instance, take the following example:

```
class Mother {
  String _name;

  Mother() {
    _name = "Default";
  }
  String get name {
    return _name;
  }
  set name (String name) {
    _name = name;
  }
}

class Child {
  Mother _mother = Mother();

  Mother get mother {
    return _mother;
  }
}

void main() {
  Child child = Child();
  Mother localMother = child.mother;
  localMother.name = "Samantha";

  print(localMother.name);  // Prints Samantha - expected
  print(child.mother.name);  // Prints Samantha - bad. The original instance inside child was mutated, without the ability for me to react inside my setter
}
```

How can I prevent the caller of child.mother from modifying the data inside the mother class?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will make sure the user gets an error on compile time:

```
class Mother {
  String _name;

  Mother() : _name = "Default";

  String get name {
    return _name;
  }
}

class _Mother extends Mother {
  set name(String name) {
    _name = name;
  }
}

class Child {
  _Mother _mother = _Mother();

  Mother get mother {
    return _mother;
  }
}

void main() {
  Child child = Child();
  Mother localMother = child.mother;
  localMother.name = "Samantha"; // There isn’t a setter named 'name' in class 'Mother'. 

  print(localMother.name); // Prints Samantha - expected
  print(child.mother
      .name); // Prints Samantha - bad. The original instance inside child was mutated, without the ability for me to react inside my setter
}
```

An alternative design (which are used a lot in the Dart SDK) is to make something like  this. A problem here is we cannot give a compile error about the use of `set` since the exception are thrown at runtime. The same behavior can be observed when using `UnmodifiableListView` from `dart:collection`:

```
abstract class Mother {
  String get name;
  set name(String name);

  factory Mother() => _Mother();
}

class _Mother implements Mother {
  String _name;

  _Mother() {
    _name = "Default";
  }
  String get name {
    return _name;
  }

  set name(String name) {
    _name = name;
  }
}

class MotherView implements Mother {
  final Mother _src;

  MotherView(this._src);

  @override
  String get name => _src.name;

  @override
  set name(String name) {
    throw UnsupportedError('Setting name');
  }
}

class Child {
  Mother _mother = Mother();

  Mother get mother => MotherView(_mother);
}

void main() {
  Child child = Child();
  Mother localMother = child.mother;
  localMother.name = "Samantha"; // UnsupportedError: Setting name

  print(localMother.name); // Prints Samantha - expected
  print(child.mother
      .name); // Prints Samantha - bad. The original instance inside child was mutated, without the ability for me to react inside my setter
}
```

Comment: Another problem is that if that even if mutating the returned object is disallowed, nothing prevents calling public mutators on that object's members (e.g., `UnmodifiableListView` prevents modifying the `List` but wouldn't prevent mutating the `List`'s elements, which would be shared).  This could be prevented by doing deep copies or by using immutable value types (such as from `package:built_value` and `package:built_collection`).